# Firebase useEffect renrendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know what I am doing wrong here but the console for currentUser is rendering every time.
I added the dependencies of the currentUser, yet it is rerendering, I have also added the cleanup, yet it is re-rendering.

```
  const [currentUser, setcurrentUser] = useState({});

  const aut = () => {
    return authentication.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDoc(user);

        userRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setcurrentUser({
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data(),
          });
        });
        console.log("inside", currentUser);
      } else {
        setcurrentUser(null);
      }
      // setcurrentUser(user);
      // createUserProfi  leDoc(user);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // aut();

  });
```

Even by using the dependencies, it returns null. If I add currentUser to [] then a never-ending loop starts with the console output.

```
  const [currentUser, setcurrentUser] = useState({});
  const [user, setUser] = useState();

  const aut = () => {
    return authentication.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      setUser(user);
      if (user) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDoc(user);

        userRef.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setcurrentUser({
            id: snapshot.id,
            ...snapshot.data(),
          });
        });
        console.log("inside", currentUser);
      } else {
        setcurrentUser(null);
      }
      // setcurrentUser(user);
      // createUserProfi  leDoc(user);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    aut();
  }, [user]);
```

this is the profileDoc FUnction

```
export const createUserProfileDoc = async (userAuth, data) => {
  if (!userAuth) return;

  const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${userAuth.uid}`);

  const snapShot = await userRef.get();

  if (!snapShot.exists) {
    const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
    const createdAt = new Date();

    try {
      await userRef.set({
        displayName,
        email,
        createdAt,
        ...data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error in creating User", error.message);
    }
  }
  return userRef;
};
```

Comment: You might need to add an empty array as dependencies for your `useEffect`: `useEffect(()=>{...}, [])`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I did that but it is still re-rendering the inside console

Comment: @RishavSinha please see my answer. you need to pass a second arg to `useEffect`. It doesn't look like you have done this in the code you posted

Comment: @RedBaron updated the code, but still, the problem is not resolved

Comment: the same code works perfectly if i use class based components

Comment: well first of all you should call `setUser(user);` inside the `if` block as this will fail without a user. can you create a filddle so we can assess further?

Answer (score 1):

this is how I handle firebase auth in my app

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            setUser(user)
        } else {
            console.log(user, 'user not loggedin')
        }
    })
}, [user])
```

I am setting the user if the user is present and I am calling `useEffect` with a second argument `[user]` to only be called if `user` has changed

Answer (score 0):

Why don't simply use AsyncStorage to save the user as Logged like this:

```
const saveDataToStorage = async (user) => {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(user));
};
```

and get the user like this in the startup screen:

```
const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
```

and only if there isn't someone saved dispatch a post request using the data you have submitted in a login form?

```
fetch("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword? key=apiKey",
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password,
                returnSecureToken: true,
            }),
        }
    );
```